# How do I build frameworks in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, frameworks, gdata

I'm trying to use the GData framework, so I downloaded it and it came as an Xcode project so I assumed I needed to build it. So I opened it up and and clicked run and it compiled fine, but where do I go to access the .framework it created? I'm new to frameworks and have only been using xcode for a month or two so you'll have to excuse my lack of knowledge about it.

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation will help you](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/wiki/BuildingTheLibrary)

Anyway, by default the target is GDataUnitTest, just change it to GDataFramework. Once you compile it you will find the framework in the folder of the XCode Project called target.